# Why interval inside switchMap stops emitting values

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to poll the user session in my application with rxjs, but only when the user session is active.

I have the user session stored in session storage. When we open the application it's null, when we login it then is refreshed and the BehaviourSubject that it is attached to is updated. Then I start an rxjs interval until the session expires so I can then call logout.

```
sessionUser$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserAuthSession>(this.getSessionUser());

private pollSessionTimeout(): void {
    this.sessionUser$
      .pipe(
        filter(user => {
          return user !== null;
        }),
        switchMap(() => interval(1000)),
        skipWhile(this.isAuthenticated),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(x => {
        console.log('Poll is deleting session', x);
        this.deleteSession();
        this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
      });
}
```

I expect that when we first launch the app and there is no user, the interval doesn't run. This is working!

I expect that after we login, a new not null sessionUser event is sent, we start the interval until the isAuthenticated (which checks if session expires) is false, and then take only 1 event to logout. This is working!

I expect that if I logout manually, a new null sessionUser event is sent which stops the interval. This is not working, as it still goes through the isAuthenticated once and calls delete one more time. Not ideal but I can work around it. The bigger problem is when I login again the interval only runs 4 times (why?) and then stops running and checking if isAuthenticated.

Any idea why this is happening? Do you suggest another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the logic you want but it seems like you could just restructure the chain you already have. Then if you want `interval` to stop emitting you can just return `EMPTY` from `switchMap`.

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
...

this.sessionUser$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return interval(1000).pipe(
          skipWhile(this.isAuthenticated),
          take(1)
        );
      } else {
        return EMPTY;
      }
    })
  ).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: wow it does work! still I don't think I understand why the skipWhile and take(1) work in the interval pipe and not outside the switchMap?

the logic I wanted is to just have the interval running when the user is logged in, where I periodically check if the session has timed out to log him out.

Comment: @talkshowhost The difference is that when you use `take()` inside `switchMap` it'll complete only the inner Observable while the outer chain is still active. If you put `take` after `switchMap` it'll complete the whole chain and it'll never ever emit anything.